# solving linear equationsystem in cpp using lapacke_dgesv

Tags: c++, lapack, intel-mkl, linear-equation

I am trying to solve a very simple equationsystem of the form M*Z=V, where M is a 2x2 Matrix, V and Z are Vectors with 2 entries. If i use `Z = linsolve( M, V );` in Matlab the result is correct.
I need to implement this in C++ somehow so I am trying to use the INTEL MKL Math library. Z should be calculated to be about [0.3091,0.6115]. But the LAPACKE_dgesv returns [1,2] for Z. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <mkl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl_lapacke.h"
using namespace std;

 int main (){
    
    const int N = 2;
    const int NRHS = 1;
    const int LDA = N;
    const int LDB = NRHS;

    MKL_INT n = N, nrhs = NRHS, lda = LDA, ldb =LDB, info;
    MKL_INT z[2];
    
    double M[LDA * N] = {
        2, 1.5388, 
        1.5388,  2,
    };

    double V[LDB * N] = {
        1.5593,
        1.6987,
    };
    

    info = LAPACKE_dgesv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, nrhs, M, lda, z, V, ldb);
    
    cout << "solution for z" "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << z[i] << "     ";
    }


}
```

Comment: It seems `z[]` is declared as an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should print V vector instead of z, z is just the pivot information.

Comment: I setup a page to discuss usage of BLAS/LAPACK/ScaLAPACK packages, please feel free to refer to them. Now it is empty, but more information will be added in a few days.
https://ericzhng.github.io/docs-matrix-library/blog/2020/08/26/installation/

Comment: You should also be aware of row-major or column-major matrix format when using BLAS/LAPACK.